# Full outer join on multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, outer-join

In PostgreSQL, I have `N` tables, each consisting of two columns: `id` and `value`. Within each table, `id` is a unique identifier and `value` is numeric.

I would like to join all the tables using `id` and, for each `id`, create a sum of `value`s of all the tables where the `id` is present (meaning the id may be present only in subset of tables).

I was trying the following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id) AS id,
       COALESCE(a.value,0) + COALESCE(b.value,0) + COALESCE(c.value.0) AS value
FROM
  a
    FULL OUTER JOIN
  b
    ON (a.id=b.id)
    FULL OUTER JOIN
  c
    ON (b.id=c.id)
```

But it doesn't work for cases when the `id` is present in `a` and `c`, but not in `b`.

I suppose I would have to do some bracketing like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(x.id, c.id) AS id, x.value+c.value AS value
FROM
    (SELECT COALESCE(a.id, b.id), a.value+b.value AS value
     FROM
       a
         FULL OUTER JOIN
       b
         ON (a.id=b.id)
    ) AS x
      FULL OUTER JOIN
    c
      ON (x.id = c.id)
```

It was only 3 tables and the code is ugly enough already imho. Is there some elegant, systematic ways how to do the join for `N` tables? Not to get lost in my code?

I would also like to point out that I did some simplifications in my example. Tables `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., are actually results of quite complex queries over several materialized views. But the syntactical problem remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood you need to sum the values from N tables and group them by id, correct?

For that I would do this:

```
Select x.id, sum (x.value) from (
     Select * from a
     Union all
     Select * from b
     Union all........
 ) as x group by x.id;
```

Since the n tables are composed by the same fields you can union them all creating a big table full of all the id - value tuples from all tables. Use union all because union filters for duplicates!
Then just sum all the values grouped by  id.